# How to start GIF from beginning on button click. - GLIDE?

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif, android-glide

Background :
I have one imageView where I want to play a GIF on button click. If I press the button again GIF should stop on pressing it again it should start again but from the beginning.

Problem :

```
        massage1.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
        if (!flag1)
        {
            GifImageView.Visibility=  ViewStates.Visible;
            Glide.With(this).Load("file:///android_asset/anki.gif").Into(imageViewTarget);

            flag1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GifImageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            flag1 = false;
            Glide.With(this).Clear(imageViewTarget);
        }
        };
```

I have used the above code to implement it but the GIF doesn't start from the beginning. It resumes from where it had stopped.

Please help me to figure out how to play the GIF from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Glide.with(LearnActivity.this)
                                        .asGif()
                                        .load(R.drawable.sample) //Your gif resource
                                        .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                                        .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                                resource.setLoopCount(1);
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .into(imgViewGif);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load GIF from disk every time when you call your method. Also set visibility after loading the GIF file:

```
 massage1.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
    if (!flag1)
    {
        GifImageView.Visibility=  ViewStates.Visible;
        Glide.With(this).Load("file:///android_asset/anki.gif").Into(imageViewTarget);

        flag1 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        GifImageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        flag1 = false;
        Glide.With(this).Clear(imageViewTarget);
    }
    };
```